# How to DNS Fallback if host not resolvable

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, debian, docker, dnsmasq

For a few docker containers I need a link between containers. This is done by docker-compose and works like a charm if (and that is sometimes the problem) the container is up.

I am looking for a solution that is working like a dns resolver who does the following:

- Try to resolve $HOSTNAME
- if $HOSTNAME is resolvable - fine, just return the IP
- if $HOSTNAME is NOT resolvable AND looks like .+?_.+?.+? - okay, return for example 127.0.0.1 as IP
- if nothing returned, return not resolvable

I tried to do this with dnsmasq, but failed, perhaps I wrote the wrong config, but all my attempts failed.

Is there a software able to do this? Does someone know if writing this in eg. GO would be a lot of work or just a three liner?

Comment: AWS Route 53 DNS does this kind of thing quite well, and the price is low. I think CloudFlare has the capability in beta, and it may be free.

Comment: Thanks for your hint. I have not yet worked with AWS Route or CloudFlare, but my problem is within the Docker network so I need to have a solution to setup myself. External DNS Systems will not be able to resolve the local containers =(.